# Удаление дублированных значений из Map

Tags: java, map, key, value

Нижеприведенный код, должен удалить из изначального списка МАП mapOfSoNameName повторяющиеся по именам элементы т.е по value. Я писал код и застрял... Каким путем пошел:

1. С помощью foreach беру элемент основого мапа  mapOfSoNameName
2. Создаю копию изначального мапа (все это позже в функцию оберну) в mapOfSoNameNameClone тут же удаляю из него элемент который взят из оснвоного мапа
3. Далее прохожусь в каждом цикле foreach с помощью цикла while каждый элемент mapOfSoNameNameClone  и сравниваю с каждым элементом mapOfSoNameName

И вот засада кроется в том что при условии if(!value.equals(entry.getValue())) копирует все значения, а по моей идее не должно и если я меняю условие  **if(value.equals(entry.getValue()))** то копирует только те которые СОВПАДАЮТ. А в моей логике сортированый мап должен быть БЕЗ совпадающих....

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Map<String, String> mapOfSoNameName = new HashMap<>();
    Map<String, String> mapOfSoNameNameSorted = new HashMap<>();
    Map<String, String> mapOfSoNameNameTemp = new HashMap<>();
    mapOfSoNameName.put("Петров", "Иван");
    mapOfSoNameName.put("Иванов", "Иван");
    mapOfSoNameName.put("Анисимов", "Николай");
    mapOfSoNameName.put("Баширов", "Азамат");
    mapOfSoNameName.put("Викулов", "Сергей");
    mapOfSoNameName.put("Мешников", "Степан");
    mapOfSoNameName.put("Мясников", "Борис");
    mapOfSoNameName.put("Каспаров", "Гари");
    mapOfSoNameName.put("Златин", "Гари");
    mapOfSoNameName.put("Южаков", "Ярослав");
    int i = 1;// для проверки
    for (Map.Entry<String, String> pairString : mapOfSoNameName.entrySet()) {
        String key = pairString.getKey();
        String value = pairString.getValue();
        Map<String, String> mapOfSoNameNameClone = new HashMap<>();
        mapOfSoNameNameClone.putAll(mapOfSoNameName);
        mapOfSoNameNameClone.remove(key, value);
        Iterator<Map.Entry<String, String>> itr = mapOfSoNameNameClone.entrySet().iterator();
        while (itr.hasNext()) {
            Map.Entry<String, String> entry = itr.next();
            if (!value.equals(entry.getValue())) {
                mapOfSoNameNameSorted.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
            }
        }
        System.out.println(i + " Изначальный список -  " + mapOfSoNameName);        // Для проверки
        System.out.println(i + " Клон  Изначального -  " + mapOfSoNameNameClone);   // Для проверки
        System.out.println(i + " Отсортированный   -   " + mapOfSoNameNameSorted);  // Для проверки
        i++; // для проверки
        mapOfSoNameNameClone.clear();
    }
}
```

Comment: А какой должен быть результат? Иванова нужно убрать? Или и Иванова и Петрова?

Comment: Сортированный список должен быть без Иванов и Гарри в частности, ну и впринципе удалаять все элементы у которых одинаковые value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сейчас по коду получается, что включаются все люди, для которых есть хоть один другой человек с несовпадающим именем. Т.е. если в списке есть люди с разными именами, то попадут все, а если у всех имя одинаковое, то никто.

Чтобы исправить код нужно для каждого человека проверять, что нет тезок, и только потом добавлять. Простое исправление может выглядеть так:

```
//есть ли тезка
boolean hasNamesake = false;
Iterator<Map.Entry<String, String>> itr = mapOfSoNameNameClone.entrySet().iterator();
while (itr.hasNext()) {
    Map.Entry<String, String> entry = itr.next();
    if (value.equals(entry.getValue())) {
        //нашли тезку
        hasNamesake = true;
        break;
    }
}
if (!hasNamesake) {
    //нету тезки, добавляем
    mapOfSoNameNameSorted.put(key, value);
}
```

Но проще обойтись вообще без цикла с помощью метода [`containsValue`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#containsValue-java.lang.Object-):

```
Map<String, String> mapOfSoNameNameClone = new HashMap<>();
mapOfSoNameNameClone.putAll(mapOfSoNameName);
mapOfSoNameNameClone.remove(key, value);
if (!mapOfSoNameNameClone.containsValue(value)) {
    mapOfSoNameNameSorted.put(key, value);
}
```

Еще лучше будет не клонировать мап на каждом шагу, а проверять дубликаты с помощью множеств.

```
//имена
Set<String> names = new HashSet<>();
//дубликаты
Set<String> duplicatedNames = new HashSet<>();
for (String name : mapOfSoNameName.values()) {
    if (names.contains(name)) {
        duplicatedNames.add(name);
    }
    names.add(name);
}

for (Map.Entry<String, String> pairString : mapOfSoNameName.entrySet()) {
    String key = pairString.getKey();
    String value = pairString.getValue();
    if (!duplicatedNames.contains(value)) {
        mapOfSoNameNameSorted.put(key, value);
    }
    System.out.println(i + " Изначальный список -  " + mapOfSoNameName);        //Для проверки
    System.out.println(i + " Отсортированный   -   " + mapOfSoNameNameSorted);  // Для проверки
    i++; // для проверки
}
```

Можно написать короче, хоть и не так эффективно, через Stream API:

```
Collection<String> names = mapOfSoNameName.values();
Set<String> duplicatedNames = names.stream().filter(n -> Collections.frequency(names, n) > 1).collect(Collectors.toSet());
Map<String, String> mapOfSoNameNameSorted = mapOfSoNameName
    .entrySet()
    .stream()
    .filter(a -> !duplicatedNames.contains(a.getValue()))
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(e -> e.getKey(), e -> e.getValue()));
System.out.println(i + " Отсортированный   -   " + mapOfSoNameNameSorted);
```

Или еще короче:

```
Map<String, String> mapOfSoNameNameSorted = mapOfSoNameName.entrySet()
    .stream()
    .filter(a -> Collections.frequency(mapOfSoNameName.values(), a.getValue()) == 1)
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(e -> e.getKey(), e -> e.getValue()));
```

P.S. Если это учебная задача, то все ОК. Но если практическая, то так хранить имена-фамилии очень странно, т.к. `Map` не поддерживает однофамильцев.
P.P.S. `HashMap` не обеспечивает что элементы будут идти по порядку. Если нужно сортировать фамилии по алфавиту, используйте `TreeMap`, если нужно хранить в порядке вставки, то `LinkedHashMap`

Comment: Спасибо! Да это учебная начал учить пару неедль назад )) Буду разбираться в ваших предложениях...

Comment: @FutureMan Пожалуйста! Добавил пару более оптимальных решений. Если проблема решена, то не забудьте отметить один из ответов как принятый. Для этого слева от ответа есть серая галочка.

Answer (score 1):

Можно развернуть карту, т. е. ключ - это значение, а значение - это ключ, и повторяющиеся ключи собрать в лист - `Map<String, List<String>>`:

```java
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("Петров", "Иван");
map.put("Иванов", "Иван");
map.put("Анисимов", "Николай");
map.put("Баширов", "Азамат");
map.put("Викулов", "Сергей");
map.put("Мешников", "Степан");
map.put("Мясников", "Борис");
map.put("Каспаров", "Гари");
map.put("Фёдоров", "Гари");
map.put("Златин", "Гари");
map.put("Южаков", "Ярослав");

Map<String, List<String>> map2 = map.entrySet().stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                e -> e.getValue(),
                e -> Collections.singletonList(e.getKey()),
                (v1, v2) -> {
                    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
                    list.addAll(v1);
                    list.addAll(v2);
                    return list;
                }));

map2.forEach((k, v) -> System.out.println(k + "=" + v));
```

Вывод:

```
Сергей=[Викулов]
Степан=[Мешников]
Николай=[Анисимов]
Борис=[Мясников]
Ярослав=[Южаков]
Азамат=[Баширов]
Иван=[Иванов, Петров]
Гари=[Фёдоров, Златин, Каспаров]
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно перегруппировать карту, т. е. значение сделать ключом, а ключи собрать в лист:

```java
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("Петров", "Иван");
map.put("Иванов", "Иван");
map.put("Анисимов", "Николай");
map.put("Баширов", "Азамат");
map.put("Викулов", "Сергей");
map.put("Мешников", "Степан");
map.put("Мясников", "Борис");
map.put("Каспаров", "Гари");
map.put("Фёдоров", "Иван");
map.put("Златин", "Гари");
map.put("Южаков", "Ярослав");

Map<String, List<String>> map2 = map.entrySet().stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                // группируем по значению в карте
                Map.Entry::getValue,
                // ключи карты собираем в лист
                Collectors.mapping(Map.Entry::getKey, Collectors.toList())));

map2.forEach((k, v) -> System.out.println(k + "=" + v));
```

Вывод:

```ini
Сергей=[Викулов]
Степан=[Мешников]
Николай=[Анисимов]
Борис=[Мясников]
Ярослав=[Южаков]
Азамат=[Баширов]
Иван=[Иванов, Петров, Фёдоров]
Гари=[Златин, Каспаров]
```